# Find the size of an SQL column with PHP?

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to build a very simple login system for my site (just for practice for a project i'm working on).  The way I've decided to implement it is use a table with fields for ID, Name, Password, and username and search for the entered information in the existing table.

For registration, it simply injects the information supplied into the table, and I would like to assign a customer ID number.  My idea for assigning an ID number is to simply find the size of the ID column (which will contain the ID's 1,2,3..etc up to the end) and assign the new registration to the length +1.  For this purpose i'll need a way to get the size of the column, but I'm just learning php and sql so i'm not sure what the syntax would be.

TLDR; is there a funtion in sql that I can use in php to get the length of a particular column?  (i.e the number of entries stored in that column?)

Comment: You're trying to reinvent SQL's `AUTO_INCREMENT` column attribute.

Comment: You want to use AUTO_INCREMENT because reinventing it like you're trying to do you will end up with duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the ID column to Primary and Auto increment.

you don't include that in your query it is created on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better off just using an IDENTITY or AUTO_INCREMENT column.  The problem with checking for the "size of the column" (by which I assume you mean the count of rows in that column) is that you could end up inserting duplicate IDs, for example:

```
ID | ...
---------
1
2
4
```

So if you did a `SELECT COUNT(ID)+1 FROM MyTable`, it would return 4, and you have an ID collision.

You could do something like `SELECT MAX(ID)+1 FROM MyTable`, but even then there could be concurrency problems (process A and process B both try to run that query at the same time, before either has a chance to insert the new ID of 5).  You're really best off just letting your RDBMS take care of it..

Comment: that sounds perfect, thanks.  I'll look into it now, like I said i'm new so I really appreciate it!

Comment: Since you're using PHP I'll assume you're using mySQL. Here's a good example of how to use mySQL's AUTO_INCREMENT keyword on columns. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html